Using %load_ext cudf.pandas throws AttributeError
I am trying to use cudf.pandas on a notebook on Kaggle and running into a long error message when enabling GPU on GridSearch. The main issue being an AttributeError on a DatFrame.
The code works fine if I remove the %load_ext cudf.pandas directive.
!nvidia-smi

Tue Jun 18 17:31:56 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4                       Off | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P8              10W /  70W |      0MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4                       Off | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P8               9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

import cudf
print("cuDF version: ", cudf.__version__)

cuDF version:  24.04.01

%load_ext cudf.pandas

import os
import gc
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import joblib

# import rdkit
# from rdkit.Chem import (AllChem, MolFromSmiles, rdMolDescriptors, 
#                         Descriptors, rdmolfiles, MolFromPDBFile)
 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.metrics import (accuracy_score, precision_score, 
                             recall_score, f1_score, classification_report)
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import shap

# Parameters grid for the cross-validation exercise
hyperparam_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1500],
    'learning_rate': [0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.15],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11],
}

# Create models and run grid search cross-validation
for p in proteins:
    # Instantiate XGBoost model
    model[p] = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=spw[p],
                             random_state=13,
                             tree_method='hist',
                             device='cuda'
                            )
    print('Model', p)
    print('Running grid search cross validation....')
    # Set up the gscv object with 4-fold
    gs_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=model[p],
                         param_grid=hyperparam_grid,
                         scoring='average_precision',
                         cv=4,
                         return_train_score=True,
                         n_jobs=-1,
                         verbose=1)

The Error Message:
Model sEH
Running grid search cross validation....
Fitting 4 folds for each of 180 candidates, totalling 720 fits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 463, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 598, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 598, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 123, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 678, in _fit_and_score
    X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 233, in _safe_split
    X_subset = _safe_indexing(X, indices)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 354, in _safe_indexing
    return _pandas_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 196, in _pandas_indexing
    return X.take(key, axis=axis)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4133, in take
    new_data = self._mgr.take(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6299, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:20

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:874, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    868     results = self._format_results(
    869         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    870     )
    872     return results
--> 874 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    876 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    877 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    878 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:1388, in GridSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1386 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1387     """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1388     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:821, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    813 if self.verbose > 0:
    814     print(
    815         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    816         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    817             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    818         )
    819     )
--> 821 out = parallel(
    822     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    823         clone(base_estimator),
    824         X,
    825         y,
    826         train=train,
    827         test=test,
    828         parameters=parameters,
    829         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    830         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    831         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    832     )
    833     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    834         enumerate(candidate_params), enumerate(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    835     )
    836 )
    838 if len(out) < 1:
    839     raise ValueError(
    840         "No fits were performed. "
    841         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    842         "Were there no candidates?"
    843     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py:63, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     58 config = get_config()
     59 iterable_with_config = (
     60     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     61     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     62 )
---> 63 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:2007, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   2001 # The first item from the output is blank, but it makes the interpreter
   2002 # progress until it enters the Try/Except block of the generator and
   2003 # reaches the first `yield` statement. This starts the asynchronous
   2004 # dispatch of the tasks to the workers.
   2005 next(output)
-> 2007 return output if self.return_generator else list(output)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1650, in Parallel._get_outputs(self, iterator, pre_dispatch)
   1647     yield
   1649     with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1650         yield from self._retrieve()
   1652 except GeneratorExit:
   1653     # The generator has been garbage collected before being fully
   1654     # consumed. This aborts the remaining tasks if possible and warn
   1655     # the user if necessary.
   1656     self._exception = True

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1754, in Parallel._retrieve(self)
   1747 while self._wait_retrieval():
   1748 
   1749     # If the callback thread of a worker has signaled that its task
   1750     # triggered an exception, or if the retrieval loop has raised an
   1751     # exception (e.g. `GeneratorExit`), exit the loop and surface the
   1752     # worker traceback.
   1753     if self._aborting:
-> 1754         self._raise_error_fast()
   1755         break
   1757     # If the next job is not ready for retrieval yet, we just wait for
   1758     # async callbacks to progress.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1789, in Parallel._raise_error_fast(self)
   1785 # If this error job exists, immediately raise the error by
   1786 # calling get_result. This job might not exists if abort has been
   1787 # called directly or if the generator is gc'ed.
   1788 if error_job is not None:
-> 1789     error_job.get_result(self.timeout)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:745, in BatchCompletionCallBack.get_result(self, timeout)
    739 backend = self.parallel._backend
    741 if backend.supports_retrieve_callback:
    742     # We assume that the result has already been retrieved by the
    743     # callback thread, and is stored internally. It's just waiting to
    744     # be returned.
--> 745     return self._return_or_raise()
    747 # For other backends, the main thread needs to run the retrieval step.
    748 try:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:763, in BatchCompletionCallBack._return_or_raise(self)
    761 try:
    762     if self.status == TASK_ERROR:
--> 763         raise self._result
    764     return self._result
    765 finally:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'


As of now (June 2024), joblib does not support cudf.pandas because the loky backend of joblib does not respect the current process's sys.meta_path when spawning new processes (similar issues exist for the multiprocessing backend, if I recall correctly). Here is a link with further discussion: https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf-pandas-integration/pull/82
This PR should help fix the problem in joblib, but it has stalled: https://github.com/joblib/joblib/pull/1525
Try changing n_jobs=-1 to n_jobs=None to run a single job. I believe this will work around the joblib failures.

Bradley Thank you kindly for the guidance and information.
